# Log if no network

Tags: networking, logs, openwrt

I have a router with OpenWRT. I noticed that sometimes (during night time) I have no internet connection. How can I log when this happens?

Comment: cron: `ping -c 1 google.com || logger "Network down"`?

Comment: or if you like to have graphs and to know on which point your network is not working you can try smokeping.